# Are there Peculiar differences between Android and IOS browsers that could make some JavaScript run in Android but not on IOS Browser?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, react-tsx, zoom-sdk

I am building an application using the Zoom Video Web SDK and so far everything has been working fine for both Desktop and Android devices. However, when I attempt to run the application on IOS Safari browser, the application does not start. It appears to have hit a fatal error that makes it not to start. But this is strange because the same application runs smoothly on Android browsers and Desktop browsers.

The difficult part is that it is hard to trace this error since the mobile IOS browsers cannot display a console for me to check where the source of the problem is. I have handled all exception-triggering code with try catch.

Since the only thing that pops up is an error message which I fired using 'antd' message, I decided to check all error/exception triggering code. I thought that by comprehensively handling the errors, then it should fix the issue but it did not.

Are there significant peculiarities to the IOS browsers? I would appreciate some helpful insights.